# Calculate area before land uplift

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I'm trying to calculate the area of an Island before a land uplift of 9 meters. I have two shapefiles, one with the polygon of the Island and one of the elevation as a pointfile (10x10 raster).

Does anyone have an idea on how to get the original area before the uplift?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your data has a projected coordinate system.
2. Open your attribute table
3. If you do not have an Area field, add a new field, call it "Area" and give it a double data type.

   4. Right click on your new area field
   5. use "Calculate Geometry" and find the area.

Comment: Calculating the area as it is now isn't the problem. If I turn the question around: How much smaller would the Island be if the land decreased by 9m (in other Words the elevation decreases). Is that still the way to go you mean Goldring?

Comment: If the elevation decreases?  So do you mean if the elevation of the island decreased by 9 meters what would be the area?  Well if you have the elevation of the area of the island, you can use that.

Read up on this link here:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/86126

Comment: Would the other way to look at this be is if sea level rose 9m how much land area is there?